# Will execution of many parallel instances of an application from NFS drive affect performance?

Tags: linux, networking, nfs, cluster, file-server

I am assembling a simple computing cluster under Ubuntu 20.04 and Slurm as a job scheduler.
The cluster will be primarily used for quantum-chemical calculations, so, as a rule, each job will run its own instance of a code on a single computing node. All nodes are connected to the head node through a 1GBit Ethernet network. I plan to keep all user files and software collection on an NSF drive on a login node while keeping local scratch space on each node.

**Will parallel independent runs of applications stored on NFS drive significantly affect performance or overload the network?**
**Does each node load the code in its RAM and then execute it locally?**

P.S. I am not a Linux expert so perhaps this question is quite naive. I am sorry in advance if that is the case.

Comment: Note that a "1GB Ethernet network" is most likely a "1Gbit Ethernet network"; so if a 100MBytes/sec network will not be stressed by your data transfers then it should be OK.

Comment: Thank you! Corrected the typo.

Comment: Heavy I/O to any storage system will impact performance. Quantum calculations is also a vague term. Some calculations read a small input file and then sit in core for weeks on end. These will not be impacted by sharing storage. Other calculations have multiple reads/writes over large data files during the course of the run. You can kill yourself on I/O here. We need more info before a definitive answer can be given.

Comment: @doneal24 I understand. Each computing node is equipped with local scratch space, so disk I/O should not be a problem I guess. Only final logs will be transferred back to the NFS storage and they usually do not exceed ~10 MBs.
Typical codes that will be used are Gaussian, ORCA, VASP, PSI4 etc. Thanks!